# Self Hosted Integration Runtime is unavailable while creating a LinkedSerive In AzureDataFactory pipeline

Tags: c#, azure-data-factory, custom-activity

[image] I wanted to load the data from my on-premises  sql db to ADLS using ADF pipeline.In order to perform this activity I need  self hosted Integration Runtime.I downloaded and configured the Integration Runtime in my local machine which is running and connected to cloud service.The problem I'm facing is the integration runtime that is running is not available while creating the linked service

Answer (score 2):

Before creating Linked Service; from “**Connections**” tab, I would request you to check the **status** of self-hosted integration run time which you have created.

[image]

If the status of self-hosted integration run time is **running**, then you can connect via integration runtime.

[image]

Hope this helps.